# If $ \sin^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, find $2x^2+1$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

If $ \sin^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2},$ find $2x^2+1$.

My attempt:
$\cos (\sin^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = 0.$

So we have $1-x^2=x^2$ which means $x= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$which would mean  $2x^2+1=2$.However, my book says that the answer is $\sqrt{5}$.

Where am I messing up?

Source:- BITSAT 2019

Comment: You are missing a close parenthesis in your attempt, which is making it harder to follow what you did

Answer (score 2):

We don't have $1-x^2=x^2$ but $\sqrt{1-x^2}=x^2$ which means $x^2=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}2$ hence $2x^2+1=\sqrt5.$

Comment: oh yeah, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out! Btw, are such questions against the policy of MSE. jUST WANTED TO KNOW

Comment: I think it was on the right side of the line, because a pen was needed to solve and you indicated your efforts. Well, now you know, but I feel your capital letters as shouting and I wonder why.

Comment: He did not know about capitals usage perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$ \sin^{-1} x + \tan ^{-1} x  = \pi/2$$

Trig identity
$$ \sin^{-1} x + \cos ^{-1} x  = \pi/2$$

Subtract
$$ \tan^{-1} x = \cos ^{-1} x $$

Take cos both sides and simplify using a right triangle construction

$$ x = \cos ( \tan ^{-1} x )= \frac{1}
{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Square and simplify

$$ x^4+x^2 -1=0,\text{ Solve quadratic  },~ x^2=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt 5}{2} $$

$$ 2 x^2+1= \pm \sqrt 5 $$

So there is one more RHS with a negative sign but that may be implied.